# Json SBJSON error - Confused about NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, json, dictionary

Hi I am new to programming.

I have some issues with NSDictionary and Table cells. I Tried to find good tutorials, but did not find anything that could help me. I am using JSONKit to parse json. I have an older version of xcode and only have simulator 4.3.

What i would like to do is to parse my Json into a table with cells.

The json I want to parse:

```
{[{"n_id":"1","name":"Green","age":"23"}]}
```

My main problem.
I dont get any errors, but when i run the app it just close automatically.
When i comment out //cell.textLabel.text = [studName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and replace it with just cell.textLabel.text = @"Test"; The app and the output works fine.
I am also able to get the NSLog(); values

I think my error is in the cell.textLabel.text = [studName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
Thanks in advance

//Json2ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



NSData * JSONdata =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.php"]];

 if([JSONdata length] == 0){
 [JSONdata release];
 return;
 }

NSArray *students =[JSONdata objectFromJSONData];

studName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *student in students)
{
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [student objectForKey:@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"Age: %@", [student objectForKey:@"age"]);

    content = [student objectForKey:@"name"];
    if(content)
       [studName addObject:content];

}

}


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [studName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

}

I am not sure about NSMutableArray.

//Json2ViewController.h

```
@interface Json2ViewController : UIViewController {
NSArray * list;
NSString * content;
NSMutableArray *studName;
```

}

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What issue do you have with NSDictionary? Are you expecting a different value?

Comment: You extract the string part in code
   //NSString * content = [results objectForKey:@"n_name"];
    content = [results objectForKey:@"n_name"];

and the in 
cell.textLabel.text = [content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
you treating it as an array. 
can you explain why and how a string "content" object behaves as like as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 //Declare NSMutableArray *studName= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in your .h file.
// 3. iterate the array; each element is a dictionary...


 for (NSDictionary *results in list)
    {
        // 3 ...that contains a string for the key "stunde"
        content = [results objectForKey:@"n_name"];
        if(content)
            [studName addObject:content];
    }
```

and in table delegate method cell for row at index

```
  // Configure the cell...
            cell.textLabel.text = [studName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Can u pls give details of the issue arises so that i can troubleshoot that issue.

Comment: I am not able to get the database values into my table. I think the error might be - cell.textLabel.text = [studName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; I do get the database values, but i am not able to get them into the cell.

Comment: Try to NSLog the values of [studName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] before assigning it to cell.textLabel.text. Check does it gives the value or not

Comment: I got this message: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'. I think i did NSMutableArray wrong. Can you maybe just check my code again concerning NSMutableArray. I am really new when it comes to programming. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: do u used numberOfRowsInTable  in  table delegate method if not then use that also.

write this after numberOf Sections method:

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [studName count];
}